# Can't install steam on ubuntu 14, 64 bit

Tags: 14.04, drivers, 64-bit, dependencies, steam

I just replaced my old win vista today with Ubuntu, a fresh install. I went to install steam, and it gave me this error.

> ```
> Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
>   libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
> ```

I try to install the packages, and it gives me this error.

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa:i386 (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.5)
>  unity-control-center : Depends: libcheese-gtk23 (>= 3.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
>                         Depends: libcheese7 (>= 3.0.1) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
> ```

I leave the window, and steam pops the error:

```
You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1'
```

I searched for other solutions and first tried a generic update.

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade;
```

It updated.

I tried from same solution:

```
wget {LIEN SUPPRIMÉ} -O /tmp/steam_1.0.0.27_i386.deb
wget {LIEN SUPPRIMÉ} -O /tmp/steam_1.0.0.27_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ia32-libs
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/steam*.deb
sudo apt-get install -fy
```

which gives me this:..

```
danny@notquitealienware:~$ wget {LIEN SUPPRIMÉ} -O /tmp/steam_1.0.0.27_i386.deb
--2015-10-14 14:03:29--  http://%7Blien/
Resolving {lien ({lien)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘{lien’
idn_encode failed (3): ‘Non-digit/letter/hyphen in input’
--2015-10-14 14:03:29--  http://supprim%C3%89%7D/
Resolving supprimÉ} (supprimÉ})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘supprimÉ}’
idn_encode failed (3): ‘Non-digit/letter/hyphen in input’
--2015-10-14 14:03:29--  http://supprim%C3%89%7D/
Resolving supprimÉ} (supprimÉ})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘supprimÉ}’
danny@notquitealienware:~$ wget {LIEN SUPPRIMÉ} -O /tmp/steam_1.0.0.27_i386.deb
--2015-10-14 14:03:45--  http://%7Blien/
Resolving {lien ({lien)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘{lien’
idn_encode failed (3): ‘Non-digit/letter/hyphen in input’
--2015-10-14 14:03:45--  http://supprim%C3%89%7D/
Resolving supprimÉ} (supprimÉ})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘supprimÉ}’
idn_encode failed (3): ‘Non-digit/letter/hyphen in input’
--2015-10-14 14:03:45--  http://supprim%C3%89%7D/
Resolving supprimÉ} (supprimÉ})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘supprimÉ}’
danny@notquitealienware:~$ wget {LIEN SUPPRIMÉ} -O /tmp/steam_1.0.0.27_amd64.deb--2015-10-14 14:03:45--  http://%7Blien/
Resolving {lien ({lien)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘{lien’
idn_encode failed (3): ‘Non-digit/letter/hyphen in input’
--2015-10-14 14:03:45--  http://supprim%C3%89%7D/
Resolving supprimÉ} (supprimÉ})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘supprimÉ}’
idn_encode failed (3): ‘Non-digit/letter/hyphen in input’
--2015-10-14 14:03:45--  http://supprim%C3%89%7D/
Resolving supprimÉ} (supprimÉ})... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘supprimÉ}’
danny@notquitealienware:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I also tried installing `ia32-libs` but get this:

```
However the following packages replace it:
  lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0

E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
danny@notquitealienware:~$
```

So I tried a new solution:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386
```

and got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gnome-session-bin : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                              libgl1
 indicator-network : Depends: unity8 (>= 7.82) but it is not going to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic:i386 : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic:i386 : Depends: libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic:i386 (= 10.3.2-0ubuntu1~trusty2) but it is not going to be installed
 libgnome-desktop-3-7 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                                 libgl1
 libqt5gui5 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                       libgl1
 libqt5multimedia5-plugins : Depends: libqgsttools-p1 (>= 5.2.1-0ubuntu5) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5quick5 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                         libgl1
 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx or
                               libgl1
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
danny@notquitealienware:~$
```

I have a 64 bit with amd radeon 4350 graphics card. I went to their website to try and update drivers, but file won't run..I have no clue what to do or how to handle this, please help

Answer (score 0):

"sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386"
"sudo apt-get update"
"Sudo apt-get install steam"
"Sudo apt-get upgrade:
You may also need to install ia32-libs; you will be able to do this after sudo apt-get update in the steps above.

Comment: That worked for me actually! Except after I rebooted, I got caught in a login screen loop (I would input password, and screen would flash and prompt password again) and couldn't even run the xerror prompt thing since it said I didnt have permissions.

Comment: Please vote up and select as correct answer. If you are still stuck in loop pleaae start new question.

Comment: Can't upvote yet, otherwise I would, but thank you.